# Canvas: bad rendering on orientation change with fragments

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

In my project i have a View, that draw a canvas.

When the acvitity/fragment is loaded everything is fine with it, and the image is rendered correctly.

But when the orientation change, it is rendered partially. 
Here are two examples:

1. Here the correct rendering

[image: This is the correct rendering]

2.This is the rendering when orientation change:

[image: Bar rendering of canvas]

The Class that i wrote extends View, and override the onDraw() method. This is the code:

```
    @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){       
     super.onDraw(canvas);  
     int size = this.width/2;
     int left = size/2;
     int right = size +left;
     canvas.drawRoundRect(resistorRects[0], 6, 6,resPaint[0]);      
     canvas.drawRect(resistorRects[FIRST_COLOR], resPaint[1]);       
     canvas.drawRect(resistorRects[SECOND_COLOR], resPaint[2]);
     canvas.drawRect(resistorRects[THIRD_COLOR], resPaint[3]);
     canvas.drawRect(resistorRects[MULTIPLIER], resPaint[4]);
     canvas.drawRect(resistorRects[TOLERANCE], resPaint[5]);
     canvas.drawLine((float)left-15, (float)16.5, (float)left, (float)17.5, resPaint[6]);
     canvas.drawLine((float)right, (float)16.5, (float)right+15, (float)17.5, resPaint[6]);
}
```

The constructor of the class is:

```
    public ResistorGraphicsView(Context context, int width) {       
    super(context);     
    this.width = width;     
    int i=0;        
    resPaint = new Paint[7];
    resistorRects = new RectF[6];
    while(i < 6){
        resPaint[i] = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        resPaint[i].setColor(Color.parseColor("#DEADBEEF"));
        i++;
    }
    int size = this.width/2;
    int left = size/2;
    int right = size +left;
    resPaint[6] = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    resPaint[6].setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"));


    resistorRects[0]= new RectF(left,0,right,35);               
    resistorRects[FIRST_COLOR]= new RectF(left+10,0,left+20,35);
    resistorRects[SECOND_COLOR]= new RectF(left+30,0,left+40,35);
    resistorRects[THIRD_COLOR] = new RectF(left+50,0, left+60,35);
    resistorRects[MULTIPLIER]= new RectF(left+70,0,left+80,35);
    resistorRects[TOLERANCE]= new RectF(right-30,0,right-20,35);                        
}
```

The strange fact is that when i select the option that inflates the layout, on the side pane the image is rendered correctly:

```
case RESISTOR_VALUE:
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.activity_container, new ResistorCalcFragment()).commit();
        break;
```

In fact, if after the bad rendering, i select it from the side pane, the view is then rendered correctly.

I tried to add some breakpoint, and it seems that everything is called correctly. Notice that every time the view is rotated i create a new instance of that object.